# responsive div flow inside another div

Tags: css, html, responsive-design

I want to flow multiple divs (function_block) inside another div (`WebPage_NavigationWrapper`). I don't want to give `WebPage_NavigationWrapper` div fix height, neither increase its height to adjust the overflow of other divs (function_block) but scrollbar appears on `WebPage_NavigationWrapper` div.

http://jsfiddle.net/toxic_kz/oqowv1wb/

Now I know I can achieve this by using display: table-cell; but then I lose width of function_blocks in case it goes over flow.

```
.function_block{
 display:table-cell;
 width:120px;
 height:60px;
 margin-left:3px;
 margin-top:3px;
 background-color:blueviolet;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/toxic_kz/oqowv1wb/

Comment: are you looking like this?? http://jsfiddle.net/oqowv1wb/4/

Comment: IF you use `overflow-x:auto`, the scrollbar will only appear when the divs are overflowing. But i'm not sure that's what you are looking for?

Comment: I want overflow with scrollbar with fixed height of WebPage_NavigationWrapper

Comment: seriously whats wrong with this question to mark negative, if you cannot answer, no problem move on ....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer; introduce another div with width in px inside the functionBlock div and give functionBlock div

```
<div class="function_block">
            <div class="function_inner_block">
                 function_block
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="function_block">
            <div class="function_inner_block">
                 function_block
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="function_block">
            <div class="function_inner_block">
                 function_block
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="function_block">
            <div class="function_inner_block">
                 function_block
            </div>
        </div>
```

and give functionBlock div display: table-cell;

```
.function_block{
display: table-cell;

/*float:left;*/
width:120px;
height:60px;
margin-left:3px;
margin-top:3px;

background-color:blueviolet;
```

}

```
.function_inner_block{
width:121px;
min-width:121px;

background-color:yellow;
}
```

now whoever put negative mark on my blog should either change to plus mark OR bring me another solution ....

Answer (score 0):

Set fixed height of parent div then scroller will enable for div.

```
#WebPage_NavigationWrapper{
   /*display: table;
   table-layout: fixed;*/
   width:100%;
   height:50px;
   padding:10px;
   overflow: auto;



}
```

Please refer following link from fiddle.

```
`http://jsfiddle.net/toxic_kz/oqowv1wb/`
```

Comment: I want overflow with scrollbar with fixed height of WebPage_NavigationWrapper

Comment: just remove `auto` add `scroll`

Answer (score -1):

Please use `overflow:auto` as `overflow:scroll` will maintain a scrollbar regardless of whether there's overflowing content or not but `auto` will only show this when it needs to.

So your code should look like this:

```
#WebPage_NavigationWrapper{
   /*display: table;
   table-layout: fixed;*/
   width:100%;
   height:auto;
   padding:10px;
   overflow-x: auto;
   overflow-y: hidden;
}
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/oqowv1wb/5/)

Comment: code still not showing scrollbar plus I want height of WebPage_NavigationWrapper div remain same in height, but I don't want to give height in px for responsive design purpose

Comment: @toxic when do you want the scrollbar to appear? Right now it's appearing when `#WebPage_NavigationWrapper` isn't wider than 120px which is the width of `.function_block`

Comment: I want overflow with scrollbar with fixed height of WebPage_NavigationWrapper

Comment: Your question states 'I don't want to give WebPage_NavigationWrapper div fix height.' Please update your code with the height value you'd like.

Comment: I don't want to give height of div in pix because i am targeting to responsive design, however in case of overflow it increase the height of div which i dont want but instead scroll from left to right

Comment: I have found answer jsfiddle.net/toxic_kz/oqowv1wb/6